# Socket support using wamp in windows 7

Tags: mysql, php, localhost

I'm running windows 7 and using WAMP for my local development. Now I Installed Cultbooking (sourceforge.net/projects/cultbooking/) in my wamp and can't finish my installation because it says sock "Socket support - Socket not supported". I don't know how I can enable my socket. I'm new to web development.

This is what I did, I download the Cultbooking from the (sourceforge.net/projects/cultbooking/) and drag the files to my 'www' directory of my wamp. Now when i pointed my browser to my localhost it say

```
  PHP version >= 5.0 Yes

  zlib compression support Available

  XML support Available

  MySQL support Available

  Socket support Unavailable

  configuration.php Writeable
```

Now my only problem is my Socket support. How do I enable it? if you're in my shoes, Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got a build of PHP installed that doesn't have [sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sockets.php) enabled. (Sockets are an abstraction that are used in code that makes and receives TCP/IP connections.)

It looks like this was [supposed to be fixed](http://bonsai.php.net/bug.php?id=8197) in the official Windows binaries back in 2002. If you're not running an official build it might help to investigate that first. If the official builds aren't being compiled with "--enable-sockets" specified then you'll need to build it youself with the option enabled.